# I do not understand why I am getting the error message Ambiguous column name 'FirstName' when compiling

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join, sql-server-2012

```
SELECT FirstName
FROM Adjuncts 
INNER JOIN Faculty ON Adjuncts.FirstName = Faculty.FirstName
```

This is my Microsoft SQL Server 2012 code. I am trying to join two tables together (`Adjuncts` and `Faculty`) and share their `FirstName`, and `LastName` columns. I tried to just do one (`FirstName`) to see if I could make it work, and could not. I was receiving the following error message:

> Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Ambiguous column name 'FirstName'

Is anyone able to tell me how to properly join the two tables together? And how to show ONLY the 'FirstName' & 'LastName' columns which are defined in each of the tables **WITHOUT** overlapping the 'FirstName' & 'LastName' columns and having them twice.

Comment: As for any subsequent question, you should ask *another* question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Are these tables really joining on the first name and last name values? There is no ID column to join them together?

Comment: You said `SELECT FirstName ...` have you tried `SELECT Adjuncts.FirstName` instead?

Comment: Asking another question for subsequent questions is how this site works.  As a new member, you are more likely to get the help you are asking us for if you follow the rules/community norms.  Please see [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transact-SQL Ambiguous column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24759157/transact-sql-ambiguous-column-name)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both tables have `FirstName` in them -- as clearly shown by the `ON` clause.

I would recommend that you use table aliases for your qualified column names:

```
SELECT a.FirstName
FROM Adjuncts a INNER JOIN
     Faculty f
     ON a.FirstName = f.FirstName;
```

Answer (score 2):

Both tables in your query (`Adjuncts` and `Faculty`) have a `FirstName` column, so you have to fully qualify it. E.g.:

```
SELECT     Adjuncts.FirstName
-- Here ---^
FROM       Adjuncts
INNER JOIN Faculty ON Adjuncts.FirstName = Faculty.FirstName
```

Comment: I changed my code to yours and now I am getting duplicate column names, and no data is being presented underneath my columns.                   SELECT Faculty.FirstName, Adjuncts.FirstName
FROM Faculty INNER JOIN Adjuncts
 ON Faculty.FirstName = Adjuncts.FirstName

Comment: Try adding Adjuncts.LastName as a column in the SELECT clause to see that column.

Comment: I think you misunderstood, The FirstName Column is showing up (twice in two different columns) and on top of that, it is not presenting any results in the rows.

Comment: could you update your question with this issue? possibly post a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following query, this might have a match so there will be data presented. It is really difficult to have a match when you are not using key columns in the `ON` clause of `JOIN`

```
SELECT a.firstname
  FROM adjuncts a
  JOIN faculty f
    ON UPPER(a.firstname) = UPPER(f.firstname)
```

Also, do not add f.firstname in the `SELECT` clause if you do not want to have two different columns for firstname.